# Updating a list with data from another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and I want to create a 3rd one combining information from both, assigning values to positions derived from the first list wit the actual values calculated from the second list... an example is probably more explanatory:

```
list1 = [ 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]
list2 = [ 0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]
```

the new list I want to create should contain the sum value of the second list across the original 1 value intervals:

```
list3 = [ 0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,0]
```

any advise?  I'm very new to python.
I'm looking to use some itertool somehow but not getting very far...

THanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: I don’t understand how the logic is supposed to work there.

Comment: How does 1+1 gives 3 or 2 depending on the case? (*edit* same for 1+0)

Comment: your logic is not clear, please explain

Comment: in List1 we have two range of 1, from index 3 to 7, and 11 to 15. So we sum range 3-7 in list2, which is 3, and we replace the one corresponding in the first list with this value, same with index from 11-15, sum in list2 of those index are 2, so we replace index 11-15 to 2 in List1.

Hope that help clarify it.

Answer (score 4):

Just one way, detecting the groups in `list1` and handling each group's corresponding elements in `list2`.

```
list1 = [ 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]
list2 = [ 0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]

from itertools import groupby, islice
it2 = iter(list2)
result = []
for k, g in groupby(list1):
    n = len(list(g))
    result += [k * sum(islice(it2, n))] * n

print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0]
```

Comment: I _finally_ managed to squeeze this into a list comp / gen exp. `[v for u in ([k * sum(g)] * len(g) for k, g in ((k, list(zip(*g))[1]) for k, g in groupby(zip(list1, list2), lambda x: x[0]))) for v in u]`. Sorry. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Looks a tiny bit complicated :-). I had actually started a solution using `zip(list1, list2)` as well, but didn't finish it because I suspected it would get uglier than my above solution, and I wouldn't have wanted to turn either solution into a oneliner...

Comment: Oh, I agree it's totally ridiculous, but it was fun to write. I could've made it a bit shorter, but I didn't want to do any redundant computations. My more sensible version is `ig0, ig1 = itemgetter(0), itemgetter(1)` `for k, g in groupby(zip(list1, list2), ig0):` `g = map(ig1, g)` `result.extend([k * sum(g)] * len(g))`, but even that's more complicated than yours.

Comment: Thank you!  much appreciated!